# Is it possible to pass a file from Spout to Bolt in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

```java
public class MySpout implements IRichSpout{
    private List fileName;  //enter code here

    public void nextTuple(){    
        File file = new File("D:/small progs/tika_document_type_detection.pdf");
        fileName.add(file);
        this.collector.emit(new Values(fileName));
    }

}

In Bolt
```

```java
public class MyBolt implements IRichBolt{
    public void execute(Tuple tuple){
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(tuple.getValues(0));
        //can i use this stream obj to parse this file(using Apache tika)
    }
}
```

Here I'm not able to pass file object from Spout to Bolt. Am i missing something in this? First of all my question is can we pass an object from Spout to Bolt using:

```java
SpoutOutCollector collecot.emit(fileName)
```

Here fileName is the list of objects which contains the file object.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not work because your Spout emit an `List` of `File` objects which gets serialized and sent to the bolt. Thus, the bolt could receive this list of `File` object like this:

```java
public void execute(Tuple tuple){
    List<File> files = (List<File>)tuple.getValue(0);
}
```

But I guess, that is not what you want...

I guess you want to sent the *content* of the file byte-by-byte from Spout to Bolt. For this, you need to open the file in `Spout.nextTuple()` and read a it byte by byte and emit a single byte via emit:

```java
FileInputStream stream = null;
public void nextTuple() {
    if(stream == null) {
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File("..."));
    }
    this.collector.emit(new Values(new Byte(stream.read()));
}
```

Of course, the bolt receive a single byte per tuple now:

```java
public void execute(Tuple tuple){
    Byte b = tuple.getByte(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but what i'm trying to do here is need to send multiple files from spout and each bolt should receive that file and extract the contents.

Comment: So what is the problem with my byte by byte suggestion? Do you Want to have a single tuple per file? If yes, just use a byte array or list of byte arrays if one is too small to hold the complete content. Or can you specify in more detail what you mean by "send multiple files"?

Comment: I am not having any problem with your suggestion, but have some doubt,  my requirement is spout will fetch multiple files(say for 1000 files) from database and spout should emit to bolt and bolt will collect the file and parse the file like (extracting the contents and metadata of the file using Apache Tika ) and now my question is will i be able to parse it if i send byte by byte

Comment: Sure can to this. If you only need an input stream you can simple read from a byte array, ie, as long a new byte of a file stream in, buffer the bytes into an array and if file is complete, handle byte array over to the input stream: `InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byte[]);`

Comment: Girish,why do you want to pass files. It looks like you want to have a worker queue build on top of Storm. It will be problematic. You should not pass content of files to Bolts but have workers that can check out reference to data and process files independently. Limitations of passing files around is size of the worker's heap, disrupter and 0MQ configs. Not sure how you will be handling retransmits within the topology.